# Recursive equation for non-recurisve equation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Determine recursive equation for: ( $A$ is any const)
$a_n = An!$

I am asking for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this good?

$$a_{n+1}=A(n+1)!=(n+1)An!=(n+1)a_n$$